# Android Layout Scrollview between two imageviews

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an image at the top of my screen and an image at the bottom. At the moment the image at the bottom is in the scrollview between them. and you must scroll down to view it. What I really would like is to have the two images static at either end of the screen and have the scrollview inbetween them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Post some of your XML code so that we can see what is going on.  Off the top of my head, I'd say you could have your main.xml have a LinearLayout with three children, set their width to FILL_PARENT and their height to 0dp.  Then, set their LAYOUT_WEIGHT to some values (1 for the images, 4 for the scrollview might be a good place to start).